# How can I publish laravel on shared web hosting without changing the directory setup?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, web-hosting

I am trying to deploy a new Laravel project on a shared hosting. I also would like to keep my Laravel project apps setup the same as if it was on my local machine "standard Laravel setup".

I used FileZilla to transfer all the files from my local machine to the web hosting.

so /public_html contains all of my laravel file and folders.

However, when I go to mydomain.com I get the provider's default page. Ans when I go to mydomain.com/public I get a white page with no errors.

Why do I get a white page when visiting mydomain.com/public?

Also, how can I make mydomain.com point to laravel's public directory?

Comment: Who are you using for the hosting? This is probably a better question for them then for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **1) Why do I get a white page when visiting mydomain.com/public?**

Probably because you did not make sure the storage folder is writable.

> **2) how can I make mydomain.com point to laravel's public directory?**

Here is an easy way of putting laravel under public directory.*

First of all, in the root of your laravel installation you have to either copy or rename the file `server.php` to `index.php` then you can use `.htaccess` so you can only access index.php or resources like css,js,fonts,images etc.. which should be located in `public/`

Here is the .htaccess i use: (put this in the root of laravel/same dir of the `server.php`)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! (\.ttf|\.woff|\.woff2|\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images|fonts)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

*(note that this solution should only be used if you have no other option other than putting laravel inside a public directory)

Comment: I have my storage folder `777` permission so that would not be the issue.  once I renamed server.php to index.php and then put the .htaccess file I am not getting 500 Internal Server error

Comment: Does your server meet the requirements for laravel 5.2 and does it have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: It should! I am hosting at fastcomet.com.

Comment: Did you check phpinfo to be sure ?

Comment: I just check their site it says they have php 5.3 by default. You need to change your php version on their cpanel. Read http://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/cpanel/php-version

Answer (score 0):

Upload your project and add **.htaccess** file in the project root directory and paste this in the .htaccess file that u have created

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
     Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
   RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ server.php
 </IfModule>
```

Then hit your domain, visit your project